How to evaluate the exact value of the sum $\sum_{x\in \Lambda_N}\frac{1}{\|x\|_2^3}$ in 2d?
Let $\Lambda_N=\{1,2,\dots,N-1,N\}^2\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^2$ be a set of lattice points in 2d. Could we evaluate the exact value of the sum below?
$$(*)\quad\sum_{x\in \Lambda_N}\frac{1}{\|x\|_2^3},\quad \text{where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$}.$$
My attempt is that in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ the Euclidean norm $|\cdot|$ is equivalent with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty},$ defined as $\|x\|=\max\{x_1,x_2\}.$ So the sum $(*)$ equals to a sum in 1d:
$$C\sum_{r=1}^N \frac{1}{r^3}r,\quad \text{where $C$ is a constant,}$$
and this sum we know how to evaluate. But this will leave the constant $C$ undetermined.
Is there any nice method to calculate the exact value of $(*)$ in terms of $N?$

What does "equivalent with" mean here?

My thinking is in 2d, we could have $\frac{1}{C}||_\infty\leq ||2 \leq C||{\infty}$ for some constant $C$, from the equavalent of norms. So we could have $(*)$ being bounded by the same sum evaluated using the supremum norm, up to a constant order. @kimchilover
